# Chrome driver is automatically terminated in Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

My chrome version is 86.0.4240.111

The chrome driver version is 86.0.4240.22.

If you write and run the code as follows, it will be automatically terminated after page loading is completed.

How to make it not automatically shut down?

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/user/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
driver = driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=%EB%84%A4%EC%9D%B4%EB%B2%84+%EB%AE%A4%EC%A7%81&oq=%EB%84%A4%EC%9D%B4%EB%B2%84+%EB%AE%A4%EC%A7%81&aqs=chrome..69i57.1528j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
driver = driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=%EB%84%A4%EC%9D%B4%EB%B2%84+%EB%AE%A4%EC%A7%81&oq=%EB%84%A4%EC%9D%B4%EB%B2%84+%EB%AE%A4%EC%A7%81&aqs=chrome..69i57.1528j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
```

Don't assign the result of the call to `driver.get` to `driver` -- you are clobbering the `driver` variable.